# How to view the v8 javascript stack?

Tags: javascript, debugging, read-eval-print-loop

For learning purposes I would like to use a tool to be able to watch the javascript stack as I write a trivial program with either break points or places where I program in pauses.  This is a part of my attempt to become more educated about computer science.  If that isn't possible then maybe a way to have snapshots of the stack at different points in the program.

I'm flailing here because I don't know what I'm talking about.

### edit

Is a stack trace what I'm looking for?  I just have to trigger a stack trace when I want to see the state of the stack?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish? Also, related: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error/Stack

Comment: I found this. Might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2060272/while-debugging-javascript-is-there-a-way-to-alert-current-call-stack

Comment: For educational purposes I want to look at the stack at different points while running a trivial script.  I'm trying to observe the stack in action. For example I might want to make a simple recursive function that divides a number and see a snapshot of the state of the stack in each recursion.

Comment: Thanks for the link.  it is helpful but I won't know if it solves my problem til I try it sometime in the next few days.

Comment: I assume you are using js in the browser? https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/javascript-debugging If not, native V8 has debug api as well, but it's a bit more complicated to set up.